# GeoServer StoreDefinition - "Markup im Dokument nach dem Root-Element muss ordnungsgemäß formatiert sein."

Tags: geoserver, php

I try to set up a GeoServer WFS-rerouting using a local PHP script that creates the GetCapabilities-document which should then be interpreted by the GeoServer.

I get the following error: (german)
"Markup im Dokument nach dem Root-Element muss ordnungsgemäß formatiert sein." (or in English "Markup in the document after the root element must be properly formatted.")

The XML is quite large, so I uploaded it to my google-drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JMUmWRVFWxsbnYpG_ZtRNSIxLseBDd5P/view?usp=sharing

This is passed back as a string to the GeoServer, but I also tried to put it into an XML object first.

Update 1:

This is a new xml where the  `<?xml version="1.0"?>` is there, also tried it with `'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?'` added in front:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hDzM7ytvATk3SZ8tD2HEOd7piYGC1V6X/view?usp=sharing

Some other thoughts:

- A Coworker suggested that it might have something to do with response headers not reported back, could this be the reason?
- Is it correct to pass the response as a string or is geoserver expecting something different?

Update 2:

I managed to get the Capabilities returned by my script to match the ones delivered by the wfs to be exactly the same, but I still get an error:

```
Error creating data store, check the parameters. Error message: Error parsing capabilities document: Vorzeitiges Dateiende.
```

Comment: GeoServer will open it if you add `<?xml version="1.0"?>` to it - but it still fails to get the layer because the server still doesn't provide what I think is a correct `describeFeatureType` document and thus GeoServer doesn't use a prefix on the geometry name.

Comment: Yeah the idea was to catch the describeFeatureType request in the second step and correct the geometry name. I will try tomorrow with the xml-version in front of it, even though I think I did this at some point before.

Comment: @iant i tried to change it (see edit in the question) but the error remains the same

Comment: I'd try setting the response header as a first thing to try

Comment: Thanks, I will try it, just got to find out how for now.

Comment: @iant how would I pass the header combined with the body as an output? i tried `echo $header echo $body` and `echo $header.$body` but didnt get it to work, am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not a PHP expert I'm afraid - all I did was drop the XML file into the `www` folder of my data directory

Comment: And you added it using New Vecotr source -> Web Feature Server (NG)?

Comment: yes, it must be served with `http` or `https` for some reason

Comment: So both getCapabilities-responses are exactly the same for both the "base"-wfs that I want to reroute and my script, still not working though.  I will edit the question again I think.

Comment: It worked! I finally got the list of the layers I want in the geoserver-interface and can go for the layer-selection etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

Step 1:
add headers:

```
header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
```

Step 2:

Make sure that you check how the urlparams are given, geoserver will change the GetCapabilities-Request to be: `url?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0` , so Request is in all caps, thus if you filter for the queryparameters, make sure to look for REQUEST.